# explanation of what my code is doing (C)

Tags: c, cstring, strcpy

```
char *extractSubstring(char *str)
{
    char temp[256];
    char *subString; // the "result"

    printf("%s\n", str); //prints #include "hello.txt"
    strcpy(temp, str); //copies string before tokenizing    

    subString = strtok(str,"\""); // find the first double quote
    subString = strtok(NULL,"\"");   // find the second double quote

    printf("%s\n", subString); //prints hello.txt

    strcpy(str, temp); //<---- the problem

    printf("%s", subString); //prints hello.txt"
    return subString;
}
```

After I strcpy, why does it add a quotation? When I comment out the 2nd strcpy line, the program works. The printfs will be deleted out of my program. I was just using it to show what was happening with my program.

Can someone please explain to me what is going on? Thank you.

Comment: You seem to be mixing your use of `str`, `temp` and `subString`, and what you use them for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is important to realize that [`strtok()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) modifies the source string in-place, and returns pointers into it.

Thus, the two calls to `strtok()` turn `str` into

```
#include \0hello.txt\0
           ^ subString points here
```

(For simplicity, I don't show the final terminating `\0`).

Now, the second ("problematic") `strcpy()` changes `str` back to:

```
#include "hello.txt"
          ^ subString still points here
```

This is what makes the `"` reappear in `subString`.

One way to fix it is by tokenizing a copy and keeping the original intact. Just make sure that your function doesn't return a pointer to an automatic variable (that would go out of scope the moment the function returns).

Comment: Wow thanks. I knew how to fix it. I just wanted to understand why it did what it did. I just tokenized the temp variable instead since I want the original argument to remain unchanged. That makes a lot of sense. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to know is that `strtok` modifies the first argument (`str`), if this is a constant (such as when calling `extractSubstring` like so: `extractSubstring("#include \"hello.txt\"");`) then this leads to *undefined behaviour*.

You already copy `str` into `temp` so you should use `temp` in your calls to `strtok`. When the tokenizing is done you should copy `subString` into a variable that you either allocate on the heap (`malloc`) or that you pass to `extractSubstring` as an extra parameter. You can't return a pointer to a local array because the array runs out of scope the the function ends.

So in summary:

```
subString = strtok(temp, "\"");
subString = strtok(NULL, "\"");

char * ret = malloc(strlen(subString));
strcpy(ret, subString);
ret[strlen(ret)] = '\0';

return ret;
```